# Error: tensor.sub(...).get is not a function

Tags: node.js, tensorflow, tensorflow.js

I am working on a vectorized implementation of linear regression using gradient descent. In order to determine how far the weights are, I am using the r^2 statistic, but when I try to get the residual and total error, I am running into problems with the tensorflow.js method "get()".

My code is as follows:

```
 function test(tfeatures, tlabels) { 
        tfeatures = tf.tensor(tfeatures);
        tlabels = tf.tensor(tlabels); 
        tfeatures = tf.ones([tfeatures.shape[0],1]).concat(tfeatures, 1);

        const predictions = tfeatures.matMul(global.weights); 

        let tactual = tlabels.sub(predictions).pow(2).sum().get();
        let tresidual = tlabels.sub(tlabels.mean()).pow(2).sum().get();

        return 1-(tresidual/tactual);
 }

//Assume global.weights is a tensor of shape [2,1].
```

When I have tried executing this code within small editors, I have no problems, however once I try to execute through the command line, I get the error:

```
TypeError: tlabels.pow(...).sum(...).sub(...).get is not a function
    at test (/home/runner/BasicFittingTests/index.js:7:48)
    at /home/runner/BasicFittingTests/index.js:20:8
    at Script.runInContext (vm.js:133:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run_dir/interp.js:156:20)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)

```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Just for the record: R^2 = 1- ((∑(actual-expected)^2)/(∑(actual - mean)^2))

Comment: What do you want to do with the `get` ? Do you want to download the data from the backend ?

Answer (score 0):

To download the tensor data from the backend, the following can be used

- `tf.data` ( and the corresponding sync `tf.dataSync`)
- `tf.array` ( and the corresponding sync `tf.arraySync`)

In any case, the data will be downloaded as an array. So the value needs to be indexed before performing the division operation